# Statement regarding the restriction of a function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

All terminology below is related to Set Theory.

**Definition**: Let $f$ be a function and $n∈N$. We say that $f$ is of order $n$ if the inverse image of each element from the range has at most $n$ corresponding elements from the domain.

**Note**: *$f$ is a functional relation if $\forall x,y,y'(\langle x,y \rangle \in f \text{ and } \langle x,y' \rangle \in f \Rightarrow y=y')$.*

**Problem**: If $f$ is a function of order $n, n > 0,$ and $A⊆Dom(f)$ then the restriction of $f$ to $f^{-1}[f[A]]$ \ $A$ is of order $n - 1$.

*This statement is quite obvious if I set for example $n=2$. However I can't seem to find a mathematical proof that shows the validity for $∀n∈N$.
[image]

Any ideas and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For $y\in f[A]$, note that $f^{-1}(\{y\}) = \bigl(f^{-1}(\{y\}) \cap A\bigr) \cup \bigl(f^{-1}(\{y\}) \setminus A\bigr)$.

Comment: This is correct but how can I use this to prove that the restriction is always of order $n-1$.

Comment: You know something about $f^{-1}(\{y\})$, and you know something about $f^{-1}(\{y\}) \cap A$. Combine those facts to deduce something about $f^{-1}(\{y\}) \setminus A$.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the hints. I've found so far that since the order of the function is n, then $|f^{−1}({y})|≤n$, $f^{-1}[f[A]]$ is the set of all elements from the domain corresponding the elements of $f[A]$. So I consider two cases. $1)$ $A=f^{−1}[A]$ then the statement is true. $2)$ $A⊂f^{−1}[A]$ then $f^{−1}({y})∖A$ is nonempty set and since $|f^{−1}({y})|≤n$ and there exists $x∈A$ then $|f^{−1}({y})∖A|≤n-1$. Do you think these observations are really correct and sufficient enough to prove the statement? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you’re on the right track in your long comment to **Daniel**, but it’s not entirely clear. First, everywhere that you’ve written $f^{-1}[A]$, you actually mean $f^{-1}[f[A]]$. Then you don’t actually need two cases: it doesn’t matter whether $f^{-1}[\{y\}]\setminus A$ is empty or not. All that matters is that it isn’t all of $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$.

I’d be inclined to organize it something like this.

> Let $D=f^{-1}[f[A]]\setminus A$. Let $y\in f[A]$, and let $F=f^{-1}[\{y\}]$. By hypothesis $|F|\le n$, and we want to show that $|F\cap D|\le n-1$. But $F\cap D=F\setminus A$, and $F\cap A\ne\varnothing$, so ... ?

Comment: Thank you again, Brian! It's a very elegant and clear approach - exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @e2l3n: My pleasure!